# copy-item a file with strange characters in filename (i.e [])

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, copy-item

I must copy a file names as follow

```
  $filename = "Sport.EL#15.csv.[]"
```

into another folder.

if I use

```
  copy-item -force Sport.EL#15.csv.[] $dest_path
```

it doesn't work.

since I do that:

```
  foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem $pathfile | Where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Where {$_.Name -match $filename}){....}
```

and the error is

```
  Bad argument to operator '-match': parsing "Sport.EL#15.csv.[]" - Unterminated [] set..
```

I think the problem is the [] in the filename. how can I workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try use:

```
copy-item -literalpath $filename $dest_path
```

Edit after comment:

to resolve the  `-match` issue try:

```
 Where {$_.Name -match [regex]::escape($filename)}
```

`-match` take a `regular expression` value and you need to `escape` each special character used in `regex language` to avoid problems like this.